# multiple version hashing passwords

Tags: php, database-design, hash

I want to design a user table in the way that website admin is able to **upgrade** password hashing algorithm.

Is it correct to use multiple version of hashing for different users and create a field called `hashingVersion (TINYINT)`?

Is it a good practice? or are there any better ways?

Comment: What do you mean "version of hashing"? You should better use a salt.

Comment: i use salt. version example: 1 for bcrypt and 2 for scrypt. now i use bcrypt, in future i would use scrypt, but some users may not login to upgrade their password.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it is good that you mentioned you use salt.

I would recommend creating **another field** inside the database to store the new version of password.

```
+-------+--------+--------+
| user  | bcrypt | scrypt |
+-------+--------+--------+
| tom   | null   | ***    |
| peter | null   | ***    |
| mary  | ***    | null   |
+-------+--------+--------+
```

The current authentication will try to verify with new hash first, and if new hash is `null`, authenticate with the old hash.

Changing password will force the deletion of old hash.
New users will use new algorithm as default.

This way one field will not have mixed information and it is easier to manage.
You may want to force users to have password change on next login so they will get new hash with salt sooner.

Because the new authentication have to work with both hashes, it must be verified before using to minimize security concerns. Otherwise a careless `or` mistake will make wrong logins possible.

Comment: the issue is that hash algorithms might not limit to two and we dont like to make 3 or more tables nor we would like to modify database each time we introduce a new algorithm.  is there any advantage of separate fields over using version field?

Comment: @amerza I see only a downside to using the option you suggested - the password field will have to be the max size of the algorithms used. If you for example have 3, which have lengths of 30, 40 and 100, your field must have a length of 100. If this is not a problem, go for it

Comment: @amerza but just as @Vlad Preda said, you may still have to modify length or something in the database when you switch algorithm. **(1)** I always tell myself to avoid mixing different data inside the same `field`. A `field` is used to store same type of data, right? But of course you may have different opinion on this. **(2)** Well but if the lengths of new and old algorithm are different, you do not even have to identify with a `hashingVersion`, but just hard code different verification according to the hash length.